# how to get data from multiple url simultaneously using Volley in Android?

Tags: android, android-volley

I know how to do this but problem is I want to fetch data if the first request fetches those data successfully and get data from first volley request. I don't how to make volley request parallelly meaning on success response of the first request we fetch data from the second URL using Volley.

**Here is my code.**

```
public class BlankHomeFragment extends Fragment {
    String url24, name;
    RecyclerView recycler;
    StringRequest autherRequest;
    Context context;
    String originalName = null, originalImage = null;
    ArrayList<String> mainList, loadList;

    String serverURL = "https://www.google.com/";   //for example site

    public BlankHomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context; //make context on fragment
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_home, container, false);
        recycler = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);

        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        //make item divider
        DividerItemDecoration decoration = new DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        recycler.addItemDecoration(decoration);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LoadRecyclDataFromServer();


        // recycler.setAdapter();
        return view;
    }

    private void LoadRecyclDataFromServer() {
        final ArrayList<String> oauth = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<String> ourl = new ArrayList<>();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, serverURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
             //you can simply get Title and description
                try {
                    //root element is JsonArray.
                    JSONArray jsarr = new JSONArray(response);
                    Log.i("response", response);
                    String title = null, auth = null, date = null,desc=null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsarr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsarr.getJSONObject(i);
                        //get id using id keys.
                        String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                        Log.i("ID ", "" + id);

                        auth = jsonObject.getString("_links");
                        date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");
                        title = jsonObject1.getString("rendered");

                        //get description.
                        JSONObject jsonDesc = jsonObject.getJSONObject("content");
                        desc=jsonDesc.getString("rendered");

                        //get Author values OR data.
                        JSONObject jsLinkArr = new JSONObject(auth);
                        String auther = jsLinkArr.get("author").toString();
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(auther);
                        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jsonArray.length(); i1++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i1);
                            //getting URL.
                            final String url = jsonObject2.getString("href");
                            Log.i("JsonLinkArrayAuth", url);

                            //below code will fetch the auther data from given url.
                            autherRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonAUthDetails = new JSONObject(response);
                                        String id;
                                        id = jsonAUthDetails.getString("id");
                                        name = jsonAUthDetails.getString("name");
                                        //get user image url.
                                        JSONObject jsonURL = jsonAUthDetails.getJSONObject("avatar_urls");
                                        url24 = jsonURL.getString("24");

                                        String url48, url96;
                                        url48 = jsonURL.getString("48");
                                        url96 = jsonURL.getString("96");

                                        Log.e("URL", url24 + "\nURL48" + url48 + "\nURL96" + url96);
                                        //get name here.
                                        oauth.add(name);
                                        ourl.add(url24);
                                        Log.i("ResponseAuth", "\nID" + id + "\nName " + name);
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    //handle Error.

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                        requestQueue.add(autherRequest);
                        autherRequest.setRetryPolicy(
                                new DefaultRetryPolicy(1 * 1000, 1, 2.0f));
                        Log.i("Responsedata", "\nAuthor : " + auth + "\nDate " + date + "\nTitle : " + title +"\nDescription"+desc+ "\nAuthName " + oauth  + "\nAuthURL " + ourl);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(request);
        Log.i("ResponsedataAuth", "\nAuthName " + oauth.toString() + "\nAuthURL " + ourl.toString());
    }
}
```